# How to use super() with arguments in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, arguments, super

I am asking this question because every single other page on SO I've Googled on the subject seems to devolve into overly simple cases or random discussions on details beyond the scope.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
        self.arg4 = arg4

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        super(Child).__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        self.arg5 = arg5
```

This is what I've tried. I get told that I need to use a type and not a classobj, but I don't know what that means and Google isn't helping.

I just want it to work. What is the correct practice in doing so in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your base class must inherit from `object` (new style class) and the call to `super` should be `super(Child, self)`.

You should also not pass `arg5` to `Base`'s `__init__`.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3
        self.arg4 = arg4

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        super(Child, self).__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        self.arg5 = arg5
```

Comment: What if the base class weren't inheriting from object?

Comment: No I mean how did people do it old style?

Comment: @user6596353 With the class name, but that isn't a recommended approach: `Base.__init__(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`